# R take maximum of cell and 0 for each element in column

Tags: r, max, apply

I am writing an objective function for a (non-linear) optimization problem in R.

Input: two columns A and B, of length N
Lets say that A_n is the n'th cel of column A, n

I do not want to use a loop as I want to code it as one function. 
I already tried:
max(A*B,0)
apply(A*B,max)
Both result each cell C_n having the maximum value of the column A*B, this makes sense to me. However, I just want to compare the outcome of each cell in A*B with zero and replace negative values by zero. How can I do that without using a loop or multiple steps?

Comment: since you state "I just want to compare the outcome of each cell in AB with zero and replace negative values by zero", you can do `AB[AB < 0] <- 0`

Comment: Thank you. Though this won't work in an objective function, as I want the operation to be part of the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `pmax`

```
pmax(A_n, 0)
#[1] 0 2 0 4
```

---

Or use `replace`

```
replace(A_n, A_n < 0, 0)
#[1] 0 2 0 4
```

#### data

```
A_n <- c(-5, 2, -3, 4)
```

Comment: @akrun. Out of curiosity, do you find an advantage of using `replace` versus subsetting? `A_n[A_n < 0] <- 0`?

Comment: @lmo  It is just that `replace` doesn't change the original vector

Comment: I see. That way you can make a modified copy (and print such a copy to the screen) and keep the original intact. Thanks for the clarification.